# Convert a Date Object excel column to Datetime string by adding a given hour column

Tags: python, date, datetime, anaconda

Can anyone solve this problem! I am trying to convert a Date object column to Datetime string format with the help of python. From 'YY-mm-dd' to 'YY/mm/dd 00:00' format. Dataset is given below. I have tried every options like `energy_df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(energy_df['Date'])`,

```
energy_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(energy_df['Date'])

energy_df['month'] = energy_df['Date'].dt.month.astype(int)
energy_df['day_of_month'] = energy_df['Date'].dt.day.astype(int)


energy_df['day_of_week'] = energy_df['Date'].dt.dayofweek.astype(int)
energy_df['hour_of_day'] = energy_df['Hours']

selected_columns = ['Date', 'day_of_week', 'hour_of_day', 'Avg Specific Humidity[g/Kg]']
energy_df = energy_df[selected_columns]
```

Dataset image:
[image: My Dataset]

Comment: to get from datetime to string, you'll want `strftime`; e.g. `pd.to_datetime(energy_df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')`

Comment: But the hour column will not be added with the Datetime string column. That will give us the Y-M-D 00:00 format.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the 'date' column to dtype `datetime`, the 'hour' column to dtype `timedelta`, add them together, and format to string.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
# some dummy input...
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-01'],
                   'hour': [1, 2, 3]})
# to datetime / timedelta...
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'], unit='h')
# and format to string...
df['timestamp'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
# will give you:
df
         date  hour            datetime         timestamp
0  2015-01-01     1 2015-01-01 01:00:00  2015/01/01 01:00
1  2015-01-01     2 2015-01-01 02:00:00  2015/01/01 02:00
2  2015-01-01     3 2015-01-01 03:00:00  2015/01/01 03:00
```